# FDQuery передать параметры

Tags: radstudio, параметры

Как с помощью FDQuery передать параметры, которые я записал в переменные, типа String, в Хранимую процедуру?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решил уже, для наглядности добавил скрины
Команда:
    `ExecSQL("execute имя процедуры параметр = значение");`